# Kernel threads list

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel

I'm looking for a list of **Linux kernel threads** with their explanation / definition.

Anyone knows where I can find this ? I've searched the web but I've found nothing... :/

Thank you very much

Comment: There isn't one. The only effective place to find this would be the source. You could probably google for some lists, but they would be incomplete. For example if you're using xfs, there are xfs threads created which don't exist if you don't use xfs.

Comment: You may try some LXR online sites like  http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=kthread_run - there is list of references to kthread_run function which is used to "kthread_run - create and wake a thread.", it was referenced in 223 files as of 4.6

Comment: Despite several research i haven't found a complete list. Thanks for your suggestions, examples and web-site